# at trial and after the trial

Tags: grammar

***At trial*** in 1921, expert witnesses disagreed about Bullet III. “**[F]irearms** identification in 1921 was in an embryonic stage,” notes forensics investigator James Starrs. The controversy surrounding Bullet III intensified **after the trial**.

Could you please explain why there is not used in the first sentence the definite article while in the second one it is so. – Maybe my second question is irrelevant for this site… but what does it generally mean when the part of the quoted text is in square brackets (like above "[F]irearms")? Is that from the reason that in the original text it is written "firearms"?

Comment: That's really 2 questions, however, 1) 'at trial' is a bit of legalese; describing the 'process' of 'being tried' rather than the 'event' of the trial itself. 2) a guess, but the [F] is possibly as you mentioned; because the original was a partial sentence.

Comment: To follow up on what Tetsujin said. "At trial" refers to the *stage in the chronology* of the legal proceedings, just as we would say "The rocket's engines malfunctioned *at lift-off*".  When the trial has been concluded, the chronology of the proceedings is ended, and thereafter the trial can be referred to as a particular completed event: "after *the* trial".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Q1: Why is there no article in "at trial"?

"At trial" is similar to "at sea", "on vacation", and "in jail". It refers to a state of being, not a specific event. "After the trial" refers to a specific trial, so it needs a definite article.

### Q2: What do square brackets in quoted text mean?

As discussed in [this ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2271/what-is-the-proper-use-of-square-brackets-in-quotes) and [this article](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/marks/bracket.htm), square brackets are used to show that you've edited a quotation. In your example, it looks like the quotation was part of a longer sentence. The 'F' is in square brackets to show that "firearms" wasn't originally capitalized.

Square brackets can also be used when you replace a word. It's common to replace pronouns with nouns to clarify the meaning of a quoted sentence. If you want to omit a word or phrase, use an [ellipsis](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/marks/ellipsis.htm) instead.